# Reinforcement learning with large number of actions to choose from

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning

In reinforcement learning, if the number of possible actions to choose from is increased, it becomes difficult to train. In many successful examples (ex: DQN), the number of possible actions to choose from is a single digit.

Is there any reinforcement learning technique that allows large number of "possible actions" to choose from? When I say large number, it should be in terms of 1,000-1,000,000. If it's more it's still better.

Thank you!

Comment: Are your actions still discrete and entirely different at the scale you are interested in? Or are they part of a space with some kind of distance metric e.g. action (2,3,4,5) is more similar in some ways to action (2,5,2,6), and both are very different to action (12,0,17,20) . . . with action similarities, then there are workable approaches.

Comment: Yes. Actions are discrete and entirely different from each other. But I am  curious how we can handle similar actions.

Comment: I suggest refine this question to give more details. Maybe ask another question about large parametric action spaces. For more clarification: Are your actions in a space like NLP (e.g. choosing which word(s) to output in a conversation)? If so, it may be possible to find a mapping - or *embedding* - that puts your otherwise discrete and arbitrary actions into a space where some form of policy gradient approach could work.

Comment: Usually this type of action space is factorizable -- "choose a number from 1 - 1 million" can be factorized into choosing 6 digits. In which case you should factorize the DQN outputs in the same way. If it's not factorable, then I don't think even a human can sensibly consider which of a million buttons to press. In that case the only thing you can do is use hierarchical softmax along with an obscene amount of training time and data.

Comment: As Neil Slater has already suggested we can actually choose correct one out of hundreds of thousands of options as in case of words. But problem is not about NLP.